# how do i get remaining stock after sales with same service tags?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

Table_1

```
Stockno|StartDate|ServiceTag|Modelno
123     2015-08-01  ABC      Inspiron
123     2015-06-01  DEF      Inspiron
123     2015-08-01  GHI      Inspiron
123     2015-08-01  JKL      Inspiron
456     2015-08-01  MNO      Galaxy
456     2015-07-01  PQR      Galaxy
456     2015-08-01  STU      Galaxy
456     2015-08-01  VWX      Galaxy
456     2015-08-01  ABC      Galaxy
```

Table_2

```
Stockno |TransDate|TransType|ServiceTag|Modelno                                  
123      2015-08-04 2100      ABC       Inspiron
123      2015-08-19 2100      GHI       Inspiron
456      2015-08-25 2100      STU       Galaxy
123      2015-07-25 2100      DEF       Inspiron
```

I have two tables. `Table_1` is available stock. `Table_2` is sold stock.

I want remaining stock after sales. I wrote the following query, it works fine but the problem is it doesnt return Galaxy with service tag= ABC(not sold) since Inspiron(servicetag=ABC) is sold. So in remaining stock I should get totally 5 records instead I get only 4.

How to correct this query?

```
Select P.Stockno,P.Modelno,P.ServiceTag, Count(P.Stockno) as ClosingBal
From Table_1 as P
Where  P.ServiceTag  Not in (Select ServiceTag from Table_2 )
Group by P.Stockno,P.Modelno,P.ServiceTag
```

Comment: Is the service tag not unique to each company?  If not your table schema may need updating.

Comment: In actual scenario its unique,but my sir asked to try if not unique.

Comment: I dont understand your stock and sales table. Are 9 items in stock? (4 inspiron + 5 galaxy) ? Are 4 items sold (1 Inspiron + 3 Galaxy) ?

Comment: Can you show us your desired results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[**SQL FIDDLE DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/2dff41/3)

Your return result isn'n clear. because if you want total you have to change the group by, and if you want show the items on stock then no need the count.

```
Select P.Stockno, P.Modelno, P.ServiceTag, Count(P.Stockno) as ClosingBal
From Table_1 as P
left join Table_2 T
    on P.Stockno = T.Stockno
   and P.ServiceTag = T.ServiceTag
Where  T.ServiceTag IS NULL
Group by P.Stockno, P.Modelno, P.ServiceTag
```

Here I match both tables using `serviceTag` and `StockNo` because you didnt include a PK/FK

Comment: Thanku Juan...Its giving my exact result!!

Answer (score 0):

Use this query:

```
select s.* from 
(
    select a.*, case when b.stock_no is null then 'in stock' else 'sold' end [status] 
    from @stock a left join @sales b on a.service_tag = b.service_tag and a.model_no = b.model_no
) s where s.status <> 'sold'
```

Output:

```
stock_no    start_dt                service_tag model_no    status
123         2015-08-01 00:00:00.000 JKL         Inspiron    in stock
456         2015-08-01 00:00:00.000 MNO         Galaxy      in stock
456         2015-07-01 00:00:00.000 PQR         Galaxy      in stock
456         2015-08-01 00:00:00.000 VWX         Galaxy      in stock
456         2015-08-01 00:00:00.000 ABC         Galaxy      in stock
```